# Finding the factor of the derived subgroup of non-abelian group of order 12

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider the group $G=\langle a,b\mid a^6=1,b^2=a^3,bab^{-1}=a^{-1} \rangle$.

The derived subgroup is $G'=\{e,a^2,a^4\}$ I believe.

So I am trying the find $G/G'$. Now I know that $|G/G'|=4$ so it will be either $C_4$ or $C_2 \times C_2$.

Ive got a feeling it will be $C_2 \times C_2$.

But ive tried

\begin{align}G/G' &= \langle \overline a,\overline b\mid\overline a^6=1,\overline b^2=\overline a^3,\overline b \overline a \overline b^{-1}=\overline a^{-1}, \overline a^2=1\rangle \\
&= \langle \overline a,\overline b\mid\overline a^2=1,\overline b^2=\overline a^3,\overline b \overline a \overline b^{-1}=\overline a^{-1} \rangle \\
&= \langle \overline a,\overline b\mid\overline a^2=1,\overline b^2=\overline a,\overline b \overline a \overline b^{-1}=\overline a \rangle \\
&= \langle \overline a,\overline b\mid\overline a^2=1,\overline b^2=\overline a,\overline b \overline a =\overline a \overline b \rangle \\
\end{align}

which is not leading where I would like it to. The $\overline b^2=\overline a$ term is causing problems.

Comment: I changed $G=\langle a,b|a^6=1,b^2=a^3,bab^{-1}=a^{-1} \rangle$ to $G=\langle a,b\mid a^6=1,b^2=a^3,bab^{-1}=a^{-1} \rangle$.  There were six instances of this and I changed all of them, using \mid. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing $G/G'$ requires just to apply an algorithm.

Write down the relations in matrix form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 0\\
3 & 2\\
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So the first line encodes $a^{6} = 1$, the second $a^{3} = b^{2}$, and the third $b a b^{-1} = a^{-1}$, abelianized as $a = a^{-1}$ or $a^{2} = 1$.

Now doing elementary row and column operations over the integers one obtains
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
3 & 2\\
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 2\\
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 2\\
0 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 4
\end{bmatrix},
$$
so it's indeed cyclic of order $4$, as
$$
G/G'\cong \mathbb{Z} / (1) \oplus \mathbb{Z} / (4).
$$.

Comment: What is this algorithm?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain and

Answer (score 2):

An idea: observe that

$$\begin{align}&bG'\neq 1\;,\;\;and\;\;(bG')^2=b^2G=a^3G'\neq 1\end{align}$$

so you already have a non-trivial element of order **not** two in $\;G/G'\;$ and thus $\;G/G'\cong C_4\;$ .